# CAPTCHA is not loading while run automation script

Tags: java, selenium

Website contact form has captcha in it and i want to test the same page bu Selenium. I have developed the Automation script for the same and placed wait before Captcha code so user have to manually enter the Captcha code and than scripts goes for Send button.

My issue is When Contact form page loads it is not loading CAPTCHA image while we Navigate manually it is working fine.What is the reason behind this and Solution for the same.

Manually loading Captcha: [image: Manually loading Captcha]

Through automation Script: [image: Not loading captcha]

Comment: Which browser do you use with Selenium? Did you test it manually with that browser too? Have you specified any special settings to that browser in Selenium? Have you tried testing it with different browsers? Have you tried visiting a different site that also has a reCaptcha captcha, did it also not show up?

Comment: i used Chrome for the selenium. I have used same browser for Manual test. I have not Done any specific setting to The browser. I have also used Firefox for the same but issue is still there in Firefox. I have not checked with other site who has a captcha

Comment: Possibly reCaptcha can detect that you are running an automated software (using the driver interface to control the browser) and therefore does not display the captcha. However that is just a guess, have no experience with captchas in Selenium.

Comment: Any javascript errors in developer console?

Answer (score 0):

Give a possbile direction to investigate. Selenium use default profile to start browser as defaul behaviour, the default profile is different from the profile we start browser manually.  Maybe the differences between profile caused your issue.

1. you can try to make selenium to start browser with the 'manual' profile, the selenium firefoxdriver support to load an exist profile.
2. look into deep on the CAPTCHA to see it's implemented by some special thing which default profile not support.